# Switching from .html to extensionless files in a directory

Tags: html, .htaccess, file, mamp

I'm trying to switch from .html to extensionless files. I'm also using MAMP so I can test it offline so I have entered a slash instead of example.com where needed in the code. I have .html on all file names but extensionless urls in all menu links with no slash on the end. When I enter localhost/example.html it reverts to localhost/example like it should and if I click on an item in the menu it goes to the correct page with the .html removed, and when I misspell something it goes to the 404 page like it should. However it's not picking up pages in a directory. Can someone let me know what needs to change?

```
ErrorDocument 404 /missing.html
AddHandler server-parsed .html
#
Options +FollowSymLinks +Includes
RewriteEngine on
#
#External redirect for extensionless url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.html
#While on Localhost  http://www.example.com is removed before / slash in the following
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
#
# Internal rewrite for extensionless url 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[^./]+)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) /$1.html [L]
#
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly you need localhost/directory/example to work when you enter localhost/directory/example.html?

Comment: For some reason it's working now when I haven't changed anything. I can go to localhost/directory/example and the pages load correctly. however when I click on one of the items in the menu from that directory page then it throws a bunch of 404s for css file, etc. I assume this is due to not being able to use full urls in the includes while on localhost.  Do you know of a workaround for this while on localhost?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will help you if you put `<base href="http://localhost/directory/">` in `<head>` part in example.html file?